# Problems installing the right version of Python

Tags: python, installation, apt-get

Has anyone had this problem: when trying to install python>=3.6.6 by typing sudo apt-get install python>=3.6.6, to get another version? I get 3.5.3 and I do not understand why it happens so.
Could anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: That version of python is the one integrated with your OS and should not be changed, as doing so would likely break your OS. Look at `pyenv` for installing alternate versions.

Comment: Yes, thank you, this worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

The version of `python` installed through `apt` is determined by the configuration in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. You can modified it to add additional sources but it is not recommended to do so since it may cause unexpected problems. A more safe way is to use `anaconda` or `miniconda` to manage your python environment. You can install any version of python through `conda`. Refer to this [tutorial](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html#installing-a-different-version-of-python).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For me, it worked with pyenv, as suggested above. But yes, your reference is also on point. :)

Comment: Personally, I would only recommend anaconda to python user's who focus on data science.